# sporadic 504 Gateway Timeout errors from WalmartLabs API

Tags: walmart-api

We are sporadically seeing 504 errors (in XML) when calling the WalmartLabs API to look up a UPC code.  We retry the same UPC and it will work a few seconds or minutes later.  It seems as if the errors come in clusters, we will get a high rate of failures (90%) and suddenly it's good again.

We are not calling the API very frequently, it's several seconds between each call.  I could add a retry loop with a timeout/max count, but I don't feel that hitting it that way is wise unless WalmartLabs folks tell me the parameters. We need a response within 1-2 seconds for this use case, otherwise we have to give up and show an error.

URL is

`http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey=<key>&upc=<upc>`

Error we get back is:

```
<errors>
    <error>
        <code>504</code>
        <message>Gateway Timeout</message>
    </error>
</errors>
```